# Spring boot : index.html loading issue

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to Spring boot sorry If I asked a stupid Question
I have made the API's using spring boot now I want to configure my "`index.htmt"` file with it.
 Which I am un able to do I keep getting issue 808 not found.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nlt6.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nlt6.jpg)

Comment: The whole question, text does not need to be a link.  Please edit your question to remove this and add a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks , Corrected it

Answer (score 0):

You've configured folder `pages/` for templates, but you are using `templates/pages/` instead. Just move your template to `src/main/resources/pages`

Comment: Made this change                                                                             
                                                                                                         
'@Bean
 public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
     InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
     resolver.setPrefix("/templates/pages/");
     resolver.setSuffix("/templates/pages/index.html");
     return resolver;
 }  '          didnt help

Comment: because a suffix is incorrect. you should set suffix to ".html"

Comment: tried moving te pages folder to resources -  didn't work 
tried setSuffix(".html"); - didnt work 
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new 
    InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/templates/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return resolver;
}

Comment: Stop, you should do one thing: move folder to resources or create InternalResourceViewResolver() as in first your comment but with right suffux

Comment: yeah, did the same didn't help

Comment: try to remove your InternalResourceViewResolver and place index.html to templates folder

Comment: Also, what URL does you open in browser?

Comment: did that before adding InternalResourceViewResolver  but the same issue 
used URL 
http://localhost:8080/AddMusicLiberaryApplication/
 and 
http://localhost:8080/ NO LUCK

Comment: please, add application.properties to your post

Comment: [gitHub Link](https://github.com/ShashankPaliwal/myrepo/tree/master/AddMusicLiberaryApplication)

Comment: please try to remove spring.mvc.static-path-pattern= from application.properties and also remove InternalResourceViewResolver and put template to templates folder

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean by put template to templates folder ??

Comment: I mean index.html

Comment: Hi I guess I was missing a tomcat dependency
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
I added that and the error seems to be gone
but I still not able to see the index.html.
Latest [Git link] (https://github.com/ShashankPaliwal/myrepo/tree/master/AddMusicLiberaryApplication/)  and tomcat logs [link] https://github.com/ShashankPaliwal/myrepo/blob/master/AddMusicLiberaryApplication/tomcat%20Server%20logs.txt ** Please Help **

Comment: Hi
try to remove spring.mvc.static-path-pattern= from application.properties and remove @Bean
 public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
  InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("/pages/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".html");
  return resolver;
 }

Comment: Tried that already its not updates the in code, but that didnt work too

Comment: I can take a look only on next week. Will respond as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks for the help, Nikolay, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Problem is resolved, solution was to add resolver.setSuffix(".html"); without the path.